# Resharper recommending adding argument

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have a piece of code that Resharper is recommending I change.

From this :

```
var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, ErrorCarrier>>>();
//some code here
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

To this :

```
var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, ErrorCarrier>>>();
//some code here
Task.WaitAll(tasks: tasks.ToArray());
```

When I investigate the reason for this, Resharper takes me to [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/CoVariantArrayConversion.html)

What am I not understanding? Why would Resharper want to add a named argument?

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I *think* R# always shows adding parameter names to the quick-fixes list. Are you sure this change was recommended by R# as a fix for the linked issue? I don't see "adding explicit parameter name" in the options for fixing this issue on your linked page.

Comment: @ikkentim I've never seen R# recommend adding a parameter type either, it's very odd. And yes, I'm sure its R#. See attached image in edit.

Comment: The hammer icon does not indicate a quick-fix, it indicates a context action. Quick fixes have light bulbs. I think the error will disappear if you use `tasks.Cast<Task>().ToArray()` Seeing there are no light bulb options, I don't think R# is providing a solution to the issue. (I think) the light bulb with the VS icon is an action provided by visual studio which normally appears in VS's own "CTRL+ ." menu

Comment: @ikkentim. Yep. That's it. You're right.

Comment: @mjwills , when I disable R#, the recommendation goes away, enabled, it comes back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, adding the argument name is not a solution suggested by ReSharper.

ReSharper shows context actions (indicated by hammers) and quick-fixes (indicated by light bulbs). ReSharper is not providing a solution to the code issue here.

The code issue can be solved by providing a `Task[]` instead of a `Task<AnyType>[]` to `Task.WaitAll` which can be achieved by using `tasks.OfType<Task>().ToArray()`.